# production environment does not work in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, production

My dev environment works correctly. But when I switch to production I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException'

with message

> 'The stream or file "C:/wamp/www/merlin/Symfony/app/logs/prod.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: No such file or directory' in C:\wamp\www\merlin\app\cache\prod\classes.php on line 4958

What is wrong ?

I have my app folder in 
`C:/wamp/www/merlin/app/`  why symfony search files in `C:/wamp/www/merlin/Symfony/app` ?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache ?

Answer (score 0):

Is file `C:/wamp/www/merlin/Symfony/app/logs/prod.log` exists? If no, try to create them manually. Also, for testing, change permissions of this file to `777` and permissions of `C:/wamp/www/merlin/Symfony/app/logs` dir to `777` too. Then try to manually remove all cache in `C:/wamp/www/merlin/Symfony/app/cache` dir.

Comment: I haven't got Symfony folder

Comment: You haven't access to it?

Comment: No, it doesn't exists. In folder merlin are:app,bin,src,vendor,web